# How to scan for peripherals in background without filtering for services on Core Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Does anyone know if I can scan for peripherals in background using Core Bluetooth without filtering for services? In my case, the peripheral that I'm trying to scan does not have any services. I have the 'bluetooth-central' permission in my Info.plist. Thanks

Comment: Simple answer; you can't.  You need to specify a service when scanning in the background. It is quite unusual for a peripheral to advertise without advertising a service.  What is it advertising?

Comment: It is advertising information like temperature and battery level and a status flag. The problem is that whoever programmed the sensor's bluetooth advertise that data in the name. So what I have to (at least the android version does it like this) is to extract the information from the name. So no services.

Comment: So then no background discovery, sorry.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 !

Answer (score -1):

Just call

```
centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
```